# Save an opencv video

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have written up a code to generate a video with bounding boxes. My current code reads and loads  the video with bounding box. Is there a way I could save the video instead of it closing all open videos.

Here is my snippet of code. Any help is appreciated

```
    fvs = FileVideoStream('./test_videos/video.mp4').start() 
    time.sleep(2.0)
    pcount = 0
    evencount = 0
    print("Model input preparation finished....")
    user = input("\nTo proceed to analysis press y\n")
out = cv2.VideoWriter('outputjcf.mp4',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m','p','4','v'), fps, (300,300))

     while (fvs.more() and pcount < 477):
    frame = fvs.read()
    if(evencount %2 == 0):
    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(frame, (300, 300)), 1.0, (300, 300), (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))
    conf_threshold = 0.4    
    net.setInput(blob)
    detections = net.forward()
    bboxes = []
    confidence = detections[0, 0, 0, 2]
    if(confidence > conf_threshold):
    x1 = int(detections[0, 0, 0, 3] * w)
    y1 = int(detections[0, 0, 0, 4] * h)
    x2 = int(detections[0, 0, 0, 5] * w)
    y2 = int(detections[0, 0, 0, 6] * h)
    if(p[pcount] < 0.85):    
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 2) 
    else:
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2) 
    else:
    continue
    evencount += 2
    pcount += 1
out.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
    fvs.stop()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
out.release()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `cv2.VideoWriter` for the same.

```py
# define fps, frame_width and frame height
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m','p','4','v'), fps, (frame_width,frame_height))

# in your loop
while ...:
    out.write(frame)


# finally
out.release()
```

Comment: i got     following error:            out = cv2.VideoWriter('outputjcf.mp4',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m','p','4','v'), fps, (300,300))
NameError: name 'fps' is not defined

Comment: i did add these three statements in my original post . do let me know if i put them in wrongloop

Comment: You have to define fps (frames per second), and frame dimensions - frame_width and frame_height.